# twitter/twemoji : There is a conflict between the country code and the alphabet

Tags: twitter, country, twemoji

I'm using twitter/twemoji now.

But sometimes conflicts unicode.

If , i choose 'p','y'(alphabet emoji), it(twemoji) is recognized as Paraguayan country code.
How can I distinguish between country codes and alphabets?